# MS Access ComboBox source Query values issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2016

here is my issue:
I have a combobox, it's source must be union of two tables. 
one table is local `AllUsers` and it has only one record:

```
    +------------+----------+
    |IndexKey    | UserName |
    +----------- +----------+
    | -1         |  ALL     |
    +-----------------------+
```

and the second one is linked from MS SQL Server`dbo_NGAC_USERINFO`, I get only Two fields from it:

```
    +-----------+----------+
    |IndexKey   | Name     |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 1         |  Tedo    |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 2         |  Tornike |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 4         |  John    |
    +----------------------+
```

so, I want to get union result of these tables, it will look like this:

```
    +-----------+----------+
    |-1         |  ALL     |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 1         |  Tedo    |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 2         |  Tornike |
    +-----------+----------+
    | 4         |  John    |
    +----------------------+
```

But my problem is:
If I write union Query, it shows blank values for `IndexKey` and correct values `Name`. but if I write select for only first or only second table in the query, it shows correct results.
here is my code that shows incorrect results:

```
SELECT *
FROM AllUsers 
UNION ALL 
SELECT dbo_NGAC_USERINFO.IndexKey, dbo_NGAC_USERINFO.Name 
FROM dbo_NGAC_USERINFO
```

**I tried**: writing the values from `AllUsers` Table manually, writing with `Union` instead of `Union All`, moving first table in the end and second at the first, ordering, creating subquery, making aliases for fieldnames, but all my tries are unsuccessful. 
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific:

```
SELECT AllUsers.IndexKey, AllUsers.Name 
FROM AllUsers 
UNION ALL 
SELECT dbo_NGAC_USERINFO.IndexKey, dbo_NGAC_USERINFO.Name 
FROM dbo_NGAC_USERINFO
```